# Profile doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the application-identifier entitlement

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, entitlements, xcarchive

I am trying to upload an app to the app store and I am getting this error on the page that has the certs. As far as I can tell I have changed the field so they have matched, but I am missing something.

[image: this is what pops up]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: info.plist]

Comment: Show your `entitlements.plist` file.

Comment: Maybe it's because I never looked for it before, but the only plists I see say info, but here is that  it's the 2nd image.

Comment: it says I can't post anymore links, I am about to get on a plane for chicago if anyone comes up with anything

Answer (score 223, accepted):

I'm not sure why this fixed it, but I went into my Target's Capabilities tab, turned iCloud ON, tried to do an archive build, it failed, I turned iCloud OFF again, tried to do an Archive build and it succeeded, and after that it was able to automatically resolve certificates again.

Comment: Just ran into this myself with Xcode 9, and toggling stuff solved it. The only "different" thing about the project is that it is ancient. Like, 2010 ancient. So maybe some legacy project file stuff going on...?

Comment: Thanks for this - after toggling on/off it has created an empty .entitlements plist next to the xcodeproj. Looks like this is what the submission process is looking for. Probably only an issue in Xcode 9 for existing apps that don't require any entitlements/capabilities.

Comment: @Echelon My project was also ancient-- originally created in 2008 and only incrementally changed since then.

Comment: Same here. Ancient project. Many thanks for the suggestion of toggling a capability, now there's an empty .entitlements that is accepted. Filing a bug with Apple.

Comment: This worked for me - only I had to delete an existing (blank) entitlement file first.

Comment: Spanked a whole evening on this bs. I had to toggle on and off, which created the blank entitlements file, and then I had to point my 'Code Signing Entitlements' build setting to that blank file.

Comment: In my case, it seemed to be the match or lack thereof between the capabilities as given in Xcode versus those specified online for the app id.

Comment: Worked for me too.  I didn't need to submit an failed Archive with iCloud turned on even.  I just turned it on and then immediately turned it off again.  I was then able to upload my next Archive to the App Store without problem.  Strange one.

Comment: Worked for me, for a new Xcode 9/Swift app. Archive worked fine, but validate had failed with the characteristic complaint. iCloud on & off again, and both validate and App Store upload worked fine. FWIW, Xcode had to create a new profile for this; maybe that's a factor, here and with ancient expired apps?

Comment: Thanks! It also worked for me with a brand new project in Xcode 9.4.1. Apple is really king with misleading error messages in Xcode...

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried turning "Keychain Sharing" on and then off again. This created the entitlements file, but no - you have to do iCloud specifically for some reason.

Comment: In Xcode 10.0beta5 this is still happening.  For me, it was due to changing the project name after entitlements were created.  Toggling iCloud on then off renamed the entitlements file and updated it's name in the build settings.  The contents of the file were identical.  It seems that the uploader cares about the name of the entitlements file regardless of the build settings file name.

Comment: I still don't know still how it worked .. But the xcode error should have a proper meaningful description with that description getting a clue is difficult

Comment: I tried turning iCloud on then off and then archiving, but I still got the same error. I turned iCloud on and left it on and then archived, and it solved the problem.

Comment: Apparently turning a capability off and on again adds a `SystemCapabilities` section to the target in the `project.pbxproj`. In my case, the error occurred when migrating an old project from manual to automatic signing. Perhaps this `SystemCapabilities` section is necessary only for automatic signing, but Xcode only adds it if you add a capability _after_ automatic signing is enabled?

Comment: How in the hell is this the answer and it actually works. /facepalm Well, thanks! Saved my sanity.

Comment: Works perfectly in Xcode 10.3
(iCloud on, iCloud off, archive again. No restart or anything else necessary). – Too bad I cannot upvote twice, because I already upvoted this answer in 2017!

Comment: Blows my mind that this is an issue that hasn't been resolved for over 2 years. Seems like if a file needs to be generated for the process you shouldn't have to hack it to make it happen (or run circles looking for this answer). Well done again Apple, you've clearly shown you're one of the leaders in developer software /s

Comment: XCode 11.2 checking in, same problem and solution

Comment: This works, because it adds an extra row to the Entitlements file with key "APS Environment" (aps-environment) and value "development". This informs validation that this entitlement is for development.

Comment: Looks like this still happens in Xcode 11.3. I had to add icloud capability and then remove it.

Comment: It is now May 2020 with Xcode 11.4.1 and this bug? still exists. I have a brand new app, bundle ID, and certificate, and it is the first attempt at validating an archive. The "fix" is still turn on iCloud capabilities and try it again. One of the many mysteries of being an iOS app developer.

Comment: I would happily give up the StackOverflow Reputation fountain here for Apple to fix this.

Comment: I think I found why this happened and why this could be fixed by these steps. But here is some additional information: You need to add the iCloud capabilities and tick all Services as well. Then, you can see that XCode tries to update the container IDs. I also selected one of the Container IDs, then unselected everything (Containers and Services). As a result, I had an <AppName>.entitlements file which had been generated. This file contains one entry "APS Environment" and two additional iCloud keys without values. Most likely the file itself and the APS entry was what's been missing before.

Comment: Just had this happen to me with Xcode 11.3.1 - after 18 successful uploads for TestFlight it suddenly happened. Fix was as above - Add iCloud capability (but did not need to tick any boxes). Archived, validated OK. Removed capability and all OK

Comment: One critical thing I recently discovered. NEVER leave iCloud turned on after this. If you accidentally (or for some reason intentionally) use iCloud, you will never be able to transfer your app to another corporate entity.

Comment: In my case, I uncheck key-value storage in iCloud, then Automatic signing works

Answer (score 50):

Rightclick on Finder -> Go to Folder...

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning
```

For Xcode 11

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
```

Delete all provisioning profiles, done.

Comment: Why does this fix the problem? What have we just deleted? Does this have any side effects?

Comment: You're deleting the provisioning profiles either added automatically by Xcode or manually by opening a profile from developer.apple.com. If you don't want to lose other profiles, you can use something like...
grep -ir YOUR_APP_ID ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles; To show which profiles match. Just delete those and it'll accomplish the same task.

Answer (score 41):

The app you created has an incorrect `application-identifier` value, for what the provisioning profile is expecting. The cert for appID `com.example.foo` for the team `2ABCDEFG` will be expecting `application-identifier: 2ABCDEFG.com.example.foo`, your app declared that its appID was `com.example.foo`, but the `application-identifier` didn't match, either you are using the wrong team-prefix, or you have the bundleID misconfigured.

In my case, I am using build schemes to allow me to build a prod app and a qa app. `com.example.foo` for prod, and `com.example.foo.qa` for QA.

I had set my bundleIdentifier in the `Info.plist` to `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)$(BUNDLE_SUFFIX)`, which works great in the simulator and on device for having different apps, however, when the app generates its `application-identifer` during the archive phase, it must not be reading the bundleIdentifier generated by the Info.plist.

To remedy the situation, I edited `FooProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` (with a text editor) to change my QA buildSettings `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` to `com.example.foo.qa`

You can see [Apple's Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1879/_index.html) and [this page](https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing/) to see their in depth dive into solving this. Once you run the following on your exported app:

```
codesign -d --entitlements :- ./Payload/myApp.app
```

and see what `application-identifier` your app was just built with, it should be pretty quick to realize what your are doing wrong.

I didn't find that page in my Google searching, because they don't actually use the phrase from the error message or call the application-identifier by its full name, but instead say App ID.

Also, the solution to this problem isn't to generate a new provisioning profile that has the `application-identifier` entitlement, it does have that entitlement, however, the value in the provisioning profile, and your app have to match.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix by changing my build settings, under packaging, to use my custom var for the suffix in the Product Bundle Identifier. e.g. *com.mycompany.myapp$(BUNDLE_ID_SUFFIX)* and this resolved it. So I did not have to edit the project file manually and was able to easily maintain different bundle ids per environment.

Comment: One reason why you can have application-identifier mismatch is that you do not have all the provisioning profiles downloaded. Your archive is created with wildcard profile if profile with exact app id is missing, which leads to mismatch in export phase.

Comment: This worked for me. I was building an Ionic app and realized I tested on a different account. I used com.foo.testName and changed it back when building with the correct account. 
It seems the com.foo.testName was still in the pbxproj file

Comment: Thanks so much, this was exactly what was blocking my validation, and the explanation is very clear!

Comment: @n8tr After almost a week of headache and frustration, your comment saved me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problem also in my App. Probably enabling and disabling the cloud, Xcode is able to fix something wrong in the certificates

Comment: I don't have any errors, I just found this question when I was learning about entitlements. But I have a question: Is the `application-identifier` generated/added at compilation time or it should be plainly visible in Xcode? Because I don't see that key in my entitlements?

Comment: Actually I think I found my answer in what you're wrote. You said the `application-identifier` only gets added during **archive** process ie even testing this on a device won't help find this issue..

Answer (score 11):

Maybe the {project}.entitlements file was missing. Doing what @samkass mentioned will auto generates the file and it will work.
So basically just go to capabilities tab, enable anything, and disable it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm developping a Flutter app with Flavors that use the --dart-define command.
I've been very inspired by this [great article](https://itnext.io/flutter-1-17-no-more-flavors-no-more-ios-schemas-command-argument-that-solves-everything-8b145ed4285d).

However I've encountered this 'application-identifier' issue when deploying.
I've tried a lot of options.
[This solution](https://medium.com/@mikaelkolkinn/i-couldnt-get-archive-exports-to-work-with-this-setup-eea478566ca3) is the one that worked for me.
It's very close to @n8tr's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148523/profile-doesnt-match-the-entitlements-files-value-for-the-application-identifi#comment83356860_47582216), but the difference was the 'instead'.

To resume, just set the Product Bundle Identifier to `your.id.here$(DEFINEEXAMPLE_APP_SUFFIX)` under Packaging in Build Settings **instead** of in Info.plist.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 11, this could happen when a .entitlement file is not present for your project. The solution would be to add any random capability by clicking on '+ Capability' under 'Signing & Capabilities' (which leads to the creation of an .entitlement file) and then removing the capability. This will let you automatically provision a certificate too.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your application features which required for your application like In **app purchase , push notification , Inter App audio , Siri kit** etc.

This is the only cause for this type  of error.

Make sure that  in your App id the above flags should be  on.

Most of time it happens when you not configured push notification , In App purchase in you development App ID.

Answer (score 2):

I went into my Target's Capabilities tab, turned Keychain Sharing ON and it starts working

Answer (score 2):

For me, the trick was to

1. add/remove a capability for the target (in my case a Widget);
2. make sure the created entitlements file is listed in the build settings;
3. and to add the "APS Environemnt" key with value "development" to the entitlemenets file.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 10, I got it working by moving the entitlements file to correct folder in Project Navigator. I didn't have the entitlements file, but I managed to get one by toggling features on capabilities tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error and none of the solutions above solved the problem in my case.

What did work for me was to change the "Can be debugged" setting in the "Entitlements.plist" file from "NO" to "YES."

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was following: provisioning profile used for build step was created for different app id than provisioning profile used for export step.

So make sure you're using the same provisioning profile for build and export step.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was that I made the archive in XCode 11, and did the upload in it Xcode 12 beta.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look, whether the **"Sign in with Apple"** capability is added along with other capabilities such as "Background Modes" & "Push Notifications"!

In my case, it was there.

So after **deleting** the **"Sign in with Apple"** capability, it got removed from the '*project*.entitlements' file and the provision profiles got synced immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Cross check capabilities in the app with options you enabled for your App Id in your developer account.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few options listed in the answers here but none helped, however, toggling the checkbox "Automatically manage signing" off and on fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: check your App ID and make sure the services are matching what's in your target.

---

What happened to me was that I let Xcode 10.1 help me create an App ID, and after that, I run into the problem as described here. (I selected whildcard app ID when I created the app in iTunesConnect, so I didn't even realized this was done.) When I opened iOS developer portal, the new app ID has Game Center and In App Purchase enabled automatically.

Since I couldn't enable Game Center in your `Target -> Capabilities`, I enabled In App Purchase, and then my app could be signed and uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

When we faced the same issue, we tried all the above things but none of it worked.

What worked for us is changing the bundle identifier so that it was not identical to the previous one, for example "com.name.App" to "com.name.App2"; let xcode attempt to fetch/create provisioning profile and then chance it back to the original one.

Got this idea from this thread on Apple's developer forums- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/114539

Answer (score 0):

I came across this page recently after trying to create a duplicate target - none of the suggestions were working for me. Further investigation, and some amount of hair pulling, eventually led me to scouring through the build settings for my app to try and figure out what was wrong.

It turned out that my project was still pointing to the entitlements file of the ORIGINAL target, rather than having one of its own. To resolve this, I navigated to the original entitlements file in Finder (e.g. **${SRCROOT}/MyProject/Entitlements/TargetName.entitlements**), created a copy within the same folder and then renamed it (e.g NewTargetName.entitlements).

Then, I opened my new entitlements file and changed the application-identifier field to match the ending of my new target's bundle identifier (e.g. **ABCDEFGH.US.co.fake-company.superduperapp-newtargetname**).

Finally, I updated the 'Code Signing Entitlements' field in the build settings to the path of my entitlements file (for me, this was something along the lines of **${SRCROOT}/MyProject/Entitlements/TargetName.entitlements**).

I returned to the Signing & Capabilities tab, and lo, the issue was fixed. Hope someone out there finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode's *Info* tab and change *Bundle identifier* field - after changing app name it didn't change even though I changed Bundle Identifier on the General tab. The above fixes did not work for me but this one did instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a brand new app, in Xcode 12 beta 3 ([app submissions started today](https://developer.apple.com/news/releases/?id=07232020a)).

Xcode had "Automatically manage signing" on. However, the Team ID displayed in the "Signing Certificate" didn't match the Team ID displayed in iTunes Connect website. This was the root cause preventing the app from being uploaded.

How I fixed it:

1. I manually created a provisioning profile for App Store distribution
2. In Xcode, I tapped on "Download manual profiles" in Preferences -> Account
3. Then, I turned off "Automatically manage signing".
4. Once I selected the provisioning profile in the dropdown, the correct Team ID appeared under "Signing Certificate"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue while setting up a Gitlab pipeline that runs exportArchive cmd and uploads to AppStore. I was able to get it to work by changing the DEVELOPMENT_TEAM in Build Settings to the same Team selected in Signing & Certs.

Because previously it was set to blank which was using another DEV TEAM id by default which was incorrect and didn't match and it was complaining about the "application-identifier" = 12331232.com.bannana.apples.peach not matching. Which lead me to setting the correct DEV TEAM and it worked.

Xcode ver: Version 11.3.1

I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

### Our Setup

Multiple targets:

- sub-apps
- watch
- app clip
- today widget

...and use iCloud.

Turning iCloud on and off was not an option for us. We already use it in production and rather not mess with it... I got the original question's message and this variation at some point as well:

> Profile doesn't match the entitlements file's values for the
> application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements.

### Solution

Hinted from other responses here, We made sure that all targets would have a `.entitlements` file. If the target had none we created an empty one like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict/>
</plist>
```

...and pointed it's target `Code Signing Entitlement` in `Build Settings` to the empty `.entitlements` file.

Solved!

Answer (score 0):

in my case , I had to put :

```
 <key>aps-environment</key>
 <string>development</string>
```

in all files with extension `.entitlements`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem because I had a wrong value in `iCloud Key-Value Store` inside the `entitlements` file. I set the following value and the error was solved:

```
iCloud Key-Value Store = $(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Removing this fixed the issue on my side.

```
OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS = "--deep";
```

My main target had this build setting and that way it overwrote the code signing entitlement of the embedded application with the parent code signing entitlement.

Answer (score 0):

Removing and creating a new Provision profile from https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list and then reinstalling it worked for me