# Profile doesn't match the entitlements file's values for the application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, code-signing-entitlements, xcode9.3

I have tried every solution from every similar question. Whenever I try to Validate an archive in Xcode 9.3 Organizer I get this error with all types of profile types. I tried exporting my project with Xcode 8 and I think it did something different with Entitlements because It exported with no problem but I tried to use application loader to upload it but Apple has this new thing where every new app must have the newest SDK.
I've toggled capabilities, I've tried with and without auto signing, I've cleaned it a bunch of times, and restarted Xcode many times. I just don't know what to do. I think there is probably something wrong with my entitlements file because I tried to fix this issue by tampering with it but I probably made it worse.

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3]

[image: screenshot4]

[image: screenshot5]

[image: screenshot6]

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Please have a look to this post...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148523/profile-doesnt-match-the-entitlements-files-value-for-the-application-identifi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Profile doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the application-identifier entitlement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148523/profile-doesnt-match-the-entitlements-files-value-for-the-application-identifi)

Answer (score 3):

Try to set a bundleIdentifier in the Info.plist to $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)$(BUNDLE_SUFFIX)
In my case it worked.

Comment: This. I had typed out the bundleidentifier in plain text as com.domain.app.watchkitapp and despite being correct, the build was rejected on upload for mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

I got no response and found no solution so I downloaded a third party app signer and uploaded to the App Store with Application Loader.

Comment: Did that resolve the issue? What 3rd party app signer did you use?