# App needs to be re-signed for app store distribution and ofile doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the application-identifier entitlement

Tags: xcode, cordova

I have created my provisioning profile correct and all of my app ids etc.

I am having this problem where when I upload the app to the app store it says *APP* needs to be re-signed for app store distribution

Then when I run it, Xcode gives me a warning and I cannot proceed further.

Profile doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the application-identifier entitlement.

I am not sure what to do. I have been troubleshooting this for about an hour or so.

I have already tried to create a new provisioning file.

Comment: Have you looked at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148523/profile-doesnt-match-the-entitlements-files-value-for-the-application-identifi

Comment: Why do you need to resign for uploading? How are you building and signing your app right now?

Comment: This solution worked for me. 

Rightclick on Finder -> Go to Folder...

~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning
Delete all provisioning profiles, done.