# Problem uploading an app to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, swiftui, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, swiftui-environment

After experimenting a bit with `SwiftUI` making a new iOS app; I just got to the point where I want to put it on TestFlight to start testing with more people.

But this is where I am hitting a new problem.
After archiving, here is what I get when trying to upload the archive to iTunes Connect:

```
Provisioning profile failed qualification

Profile doesn't match the entitlements file's values for the application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements.
```

As far as I can tell, I am not doing anything more or less than I always did in the past, when uploading a new app.

Here is what I can say about the app:

- It is using `SwiftUI`. (This is the first time I upload a `SwiftUI` app, if that ever matters here)
- It is using `Core Data`.
- It is using `MapKit`.
- It is using location triggered notifications.

For the environment:

- I just upgraded Xcode to version 11.6 (11E708)
- I am using Mac OS Catalina version 10.15.6.

Is there anyone who has faced the same situation before?

Or is there something to check knowing the information above?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem since around July.
Here is what worked for me.

1. Archive the project on Xcode11,
2. Open the Organizer window on Xcode12 Beta
3. And as usual, you can try uploading from there,

BUT in my case, Here, I faced another issue saying failed to 'APP STORE connect operation error'.
If you face this same error like this, then here are other steps you should take.

4. Download 'transporter' from the Mac app store.
5. on the Xcode 12 Beta organizer window, instead of uploading the app, click export the app.
6. Then open the transporter, and add the file you just exported, then you will see 'Deliver' button. After clicking it , in my case, the app was uploaded in a couple of minutes.

Hope it works for you too.

Xcode11: Version 11.5 (for archive)

Xcode12: Version 12.0 beta (for exporting a project on organizer)

My Mac: macOS Big Sur Version 11.0 Beta

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will dig into that then. Is seems like it's a new trouble that we did have up to now. And if possible I would like to avoid dealing with a beta Xcode.

Comment: Can't assure you 100%. But recommend you using Xdoe 12 Beta for the organizer window. In my case, Xcode stopped saying 'Provisioning profile failed qualification' when using the organizer of Xcode12 Beta. And since the project was archived Xcode11, app being rejected reason of 'Buit on beta version of Xcode' won't happen. :)

Comment: were you using automatic profile management or manual? I wanted to use automatic, but gave up and finally made it work using manual settings, without having to use beta Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! Yes, I was using the automatic profile management. Maybe next time I also won't need to use beta-version either. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you need to check the capabilities. The capabilities in the project needs to be equal to which you configurated in the section of "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" in the app. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148523/profile-doesnt-match-the-entitlements-files-value-for-the-application-identifi#:%7E:text=So%20basically%20just%20go%20to,enable%20anything%2C%20and%20disable%20it.&text=Changing%20the%20iCloud%20toggle%20to,keychain%2Daccess%2Dgroups%20entitlements.) you can find more info