# Xcode : Error on post application to app store

Tags: xcode, flutter

I try to post a archive application to app store connect but i have this issue, how can i fix it?

[image]

Comment: Which version of macOS are you using ?

Comment: i using macOS Big Sur version : 11.2.3

Comment: probably this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46332693/10595176